# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth scan finds no devices but AC7265 driver is ok?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, bluetooth, intel

I'm having trouble getting XUbuntu 18.04 to see any Bluetooth devices when searching for devices to pair with (e.g. headset) using an Intel AC7265 (which I *think* is a combined 802.11 and BT radio). `bluetoothctl` responds to commands (e.g. `power on`, `scan on` etc.) but never shows any devices. I get similar experience through `blueman-manager`.

I've read several threads of clues but without much success and everything obvious looks ok to me, so I am a bit puzzled.

Any clues where this might be going wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated - thank you!!

**uname -a**

```
Linux my-desktop 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -knn | grep Wireless -A3**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**lsusb -t | grep Wireless**

```
    |__ Port 7: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

**dmesg | grep -i blue**

```
[    5.322514] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.322537] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.322540] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.322544] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.322551] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.390392] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e23
[    5.390395] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 23
[    6.380923] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.380925] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.380929] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.689755] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.689763] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.689768] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

**sudo rfkill list**

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**hciconfig**

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 34:13:E8:1E:75:E8  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:667 acl:0 sco:0 events:43 errors:0
    TX bytes:976 acl:0 sco:0 commands:43 errors:0
```

**sudo service bluetooth status**

```
â bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-05-09 12:35:49 BST; 1h 5min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 5805 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           ââ5805 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 09 12:35:48 my-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop bluetoothd[5805]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop bluetoothd[5805]: Starting SDP server
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop bluetoothd[5805]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop bluetoothd[5805]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
May 09 12:35:49 my-desktop bluetoothd[5805]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

**bluetoothctl**

```
bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 34:13:E8:1E:75:E8 xubuntu-0 [default]
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 34:13:E8:1E:75:E8 xubuntu-0 [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 34:13:E8:1E:75:E8 Discovering: yes
(... time passes ...)
[bluetooth]# devices
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: This appeared to be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.

It turns out this was a hardware issue. The chassis antenna leads had become detached from the WiFi card. Plugged these in and hey, presto - everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem for a while now, and today decided I would look into it. After searching around on the web, just like you, I could not find a solution. The outputs I received are very similar to the ones you show. The only thing I could also find is an error in the syslog was an error:

`error updating services: Host is down (112)`

I was about to give up and throw in the towel, when I noticed that in some of the outputs (e.g. for rfkill) the wlan device is also mentioned. And it just so happened to be that I switched to a wired network connection a while ago. I could not see how it should matter, but I was able to fix the bluetooth problem, by switching on the WiFi!

I don't know if it helps, if not for you, then perhaps someone else who stumbles across this thread.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting to note. I've realised since that the WiFi isn't working either. My best guess is that the device id of this card isn't getting recognised and so the drive isn't loading properly. I still haven't been able to figure this out.